# Where to add acknowledgement in Article

Tags: publications, acknowledgement

I have written an article (2-column type), and would like to put an acknowledgement to acknowledge the non-substantial contribution of a colleague in the analysis of some data.

The structure of the article is

```
Introduction
Main body
-> chapter with the data
Conclusion
References
```

Where and how should I put the acknowledgements?

Comment: Consult the guidelines of the journal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acknowledgement is usually placed between the conclusion and the references.

You should write a sentence mentioning how the other person or persons contributed to the paper or your work.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it is also possible in some cases, to work in the thanks in the introduction, especially if the contribution is what actually led to this work.

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry about this. Add it wherever you believe it fits. The editors of the journal will move it to the place where *they* like it (or tell you to do so). It is widely considered a matter of journal style, similar to the question of whether the Preface counts as Section 1 or as an unnumbered extra section. (I'm speaking for mathematics, but I have no reasons to think this is different in other subjects.)